# Why can't I store the file directory in a variable for use with csv.reader(file())?

Tags: python, variables, filepath

I need to store a file directory in a variable because it will be used later. In my script below I want to print out the contents but I got a `TypeError: 'file' object is not callable`.

The script:

```
posfile = 'C:/Users/name/Desktop/textfile.txt'
csv_data=csv.reader(file(posfile))
count_test = 0
for row in csv_data:
    count_test = count_test + 1
    print count_test, row
```

Comment: I don't get that error, and your code looks fine - there's nothing wrong with storing a filename in a variable, at any rate. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.6 I seriously got that error

Comment: I'd guess that somewhere above this code you did something like `file = open(...)`

Comment: I'd put money that @Daenyth is right, which makes the call to `file()` fail (regardless of what arguments you try to call it with).

Comment: @ThanaDaray if Daenyth is wrong, provide a code sample that demonstrates the  problem when run in isolation -- right now, none of us can reproduce it. The "solution" you accepted, changing `file()` to `open()`, just works around the problem -- that problem being that you've clearly shadowed the `file` builtin elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I really do not have that so what you want me to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
posfile = 'C:/Users/name/Desktop/textfile.txt'
csv_data=csv.reader(open(posfile, 'rb'))
count_test = 0
for row in csv_data:
    count_test = count_test + 1
    print count_test, row
```

You may also want to check that you haven't changed the value of file some other place in your code.

```
file(posfile)
```

should work.

If you've done something like file = somefile. Earlier in the code you could have problems. because file is no longer a file object.